# git looking for ssh at new location

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10

Due to some installations, my ssh key paths got modified.
So now if I run some git command, like 'git pull -r', I get this:

> Enter passphrase for key '/new/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa':

I want to 2 do things:

1. Dont want to enter passphrase everytime.
2. Want id_rsa location to some default of my choice and make git know it.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the passphrase, see "[How do I remove the passphrase for the SSH key without having to create a new key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/6309)".
`ssh-keygen` is available in Windows 10, as packaged with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Regarding the new path, you can:

- either move it back in %USERPROFILE%.ssh (both public and private key)
- or create a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config` file which will reference the new path of your key. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374944/6309) as an example.