# using ssh to connect to live server and push my git into it

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I have an IP and `guest_key` from a live linux server.

I am getting error when I try to ssh into the server or use push on it.

Every time I try, I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error i

I have tried to push my local Git app into production by ssh like below

```
git remote add production ssh://root@3******0/var/repo/site.git
```

how can I add my key to git bash line so that server gives me permission.
I am using windows and git bash for that.

```
root@**MyIpAdress**: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Can somebody help me with that: I mean can we directly ssh into live server or just by pushing by Git ?

Comment: May or may not b a server configuration issue. Try to connect with regular `ssh` to the server. Add `-vv` for more verbose output. You probably also shouldn't use the root account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it would be really surprising to be using the `root` account for a remote SSH session.
This is not considered a good practice (since `root` can do anything), and a service account like "`git`" (or any regular account you want) is recommended.

Second, you need to add your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the remote server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, in order for any SSH call to have a chance to complete.

If your key is not named `id_rsa(.pub)`, then, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374944/6309), you need to define an entry (for instance 'xxx') which will reference your actual private key.

Then your URL would be:

```
cd C:\path\to\repo
git remote set-url production xxx:/var/repo/site.git
git push production master
```

But again, try and avoid using `root` on the remote server. 
(even [`sudo` is dangerous](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/82549))